# Why do I keep getting an 'expected a declaration' error in my package.json file in ReactJS and how can I resolve it?

Tags: reactjs, package.json

I always keep getting this error of "expected a declaration" at the beggining of every React app I create. My apps seem to work just fine but I am bothered by it an wonder if it might be causing some issue that I am not yet able to see. Is there any way I could remove this error?

[The error I get at the beginning of every package.json file of any React App I create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqO2s.png)

I have rechecked multiple times and yes the closing bracket is there at the end but nothing seems to solve my issue. It would be a great help if someone could tell me what is going on. I am suspecting some problem in my VS Code installation.

Here is my package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "reactappdev",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "framer-motion": "^8.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` here?

Comment: Added package.json

Comment: Have you installed a C++/C related extensions? try uninstall/disable those?

Comment: yes I have installed all required extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon your VS Code Intellisense isn't configured to handle files of type 'json'. If you look at the raised error, it is marking that as an error according to "C/C++" expectations.